# multiple values in one column table in php

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

i have a problem making a pdf i have 2 tables in database book and author and the problem is if the book is 2 or more author i can`t show it in just one column below is the image of join book and author and the pdf i make.

**My Data There`s a 2 author how to make them one row or join them in one column**

[image: My Data There`s a 2 author how to make them one row or join them in one column]

**The pdf that i make below is the code**

[image: The pdf that i make below is the code]

```
$sqlpatient = mysqli_query($connect, "select * from book");  
   $rowpatient = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlpatient);

                do{
                    if(mysqli_num_rows($sqlpatient) != 0){  
                $bookid = $rowpatient['bookid'];
            $authorsql = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT author FROM author WHERE bookid = '$bookid' ");
  $output .= '<tr>  
                      <td>'.$rowpatient["bookid"].'</td>  
                      <td>'.$rowpatient["callnumber"].'</td>  
                      <td>'.$rowpatient["isbn"].'</td>  
                      <td>'.$rowpatient["bookname"].'</td>  '; 
                      while ($authorrow = mysqli_fetch_array($authorsql)) {
                      $author =  $authorrow["author"].",";

                       $output .= '<td>'. $author.'</td>';
                   }
                     $output .= ' <td style="text-transform: capitalize;">'.$rowpatient["genre"].'</td>
                     <td>'.$rowpatient["publisher"].'</td>  
                      <td>'.$rowpatient["publishdate"].'</td>  
                 </tr>  
                      ';  

   }
                }while($rowpatient = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlpatient));  
  return $output;
```

Comment: the other author move to the category and i don`t know why

Comment: You're creating a new `<td></td>` pair on each author. You should only have _one_  `<td></td>` around the output of your loop if you want them in the same column.

Comment: thanks sensei it really helps it work btw

Comment: Feel free to accept my answer below if it helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you're creating a new `<td></td>` pair inside your loop for each author, which is what messes it up if there are more than one.

Try adding all the authors to a string and then have *one* `<td></td>` pair after the loop:

```
// Define an empty string that we will append all authors to
$authors = '';

while ($authorrow = mysqli_fetch_array($authorsql)) {
    $authors .= $authorrow["author"].",";
}

// I've used trim() to trim away the trailing comma.
$output .= '<td>' . trim($authors, ',') .  '</td>';
```

Comment: thanks sensei that`s is my problem right now ahahahaha

Answer (score 1):

you can create an empty string, and inside your while loop concatenate it with the author's name, when the loop ends, the variable created will have all the authors' names, then u can create a table column and put the variable inside.
You can do this or create an array and push the values to it inside the loop, and then use implode function with ',' that returns a string of the array elements, Check https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_implode.asp

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding of the question, you need to use implode() function

```
<?php
$arr = array('Hello','World!','Beautiful','Day!');
echo implode(" ",$arr);
?>
```

output:- Hello World! Beautiful Day!